# How to repeat row based on qty field

Tags: mysql

I have a table like

```
id product qty
1  apples  3
2  oranges 1
```

I want to get a query that will return

```
1  apples  1
1  apples  1
1  apples  1
2  oranges 1
```

How do I accomplish that? I've seen several answers on splitting a column into rows like "a,b,c" but not on qty like this. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why would you want multiple identical rows in a result set?

Comment: because on a diffrent table we store them item by item and it would make it easier to compare and join. and no unfortunately i can't fix those tables :(

Answer (score 4):

You need a table of numbers, and fill this table with sequential number as much as you want.

```
CREATE TABLE numbers (
    number int
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

INSERT INTO numbers (number) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5); -- you can add more number according your needs.
```

And then join this table with your table.

```
SELECT p.id, p.product, 1
FROM products p
     JOIN numbers n ON p.qty >= n.number;
```

This should produce result as you want.

If you can't create table, you can simulate table with UNION.

```
SELECT p.id, p.product, 1
FROM products p
    JOIN (
                SELECT 1 as number UNION
                SELECT 2 UNION
                SELECT 3 -- you can continue this line
               ) n
    ON p.qty >= n.number;
```

Comment: sorry needs to be a query solution not table solution. can't create that table

Comment: This is a query. The table needs to be created once.

Comment: like i said. i can't create that table

Comment: It's hard to achieve without help of additional table. Perhaps someone has more brilliant idea.

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT p.id, p.product, 1
FROM products p
    JOIN (
        SELECT @row := @row + 1 as row FROM 
        (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) t,
        (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) t2,
        (SELECT @row:=0) r
    ) n ON p.qty >= n.row;
```